# Many of axis labels

Tags: axis, jqplot, label

Could somebody help mi with http://www.jqplot.com/tests/axisLabelTests.php

I need to insert three axis on picture but I don't know how.

Comment: can you please be more specific in telling us which side you want the axis, you want an xaxis or yaxis and any other details regarding your question.

Comment: I need something like this:       https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/74/Normal_Distribution_PDF.svg/350px-Normal_Distribution_PDF.svg.png

Comment: I don't know how I can create graph with this plot:   http://www.jqplot.com/tests/axisLabelTests.php I need three lines

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples of what you want in the following links [jqPlot documentation] :

[- First example](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/rotated-tick-labels.php)

[- Second example](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/zooming.php)

[And finally, Axis documentation here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis)

**Edit** According to your comment attached to your original post, you can do something [like this (jsFiddle link)](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/7Hq8L/) :

```
//Declare a first series
var cosPoints = [...];
//Declare a second one
var cosPoints2 = [...];
//Draw a new plot with those two series
$.jqplot('chart1', [cosPoints,cosPoints2], {});
//You will obtain a graph with two lines representing your two series.
```

**PS** I think you definitely need to take a look at jqPlot examples [here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/) and [here](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/)

Comment: Please see my updated answer hereabove and refer to [this jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/7Hq8L/)

Comment: Thank but why te line aren't the same ?

Comment: Because the definitions of variable aren't the same (cos(i) for cosPoints and cos(i-1) for cosPoints2)

Comment: Ok, so tell me how to do the same line color. That's my problem indeed.

Comment: Please see [updated jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/7Hq8L/1/)    But seriously read jqPlot documentation and examples (almost everything is clearly explained - at least what you have needed so far...)

Comment: If previous post and comments answers your question please tag corresponding post as answer.